# TFS Build 2015 - Build procedure using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: tfs-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on Auto Deployment using TFS 2015 new build functionality for my MVC application. The solution has some web service projects as well, along with other projects. As a first step, I am trying to create a build and I identified we need to create Paramters.xml file to have configuration variables configured in this file. I believe, subsequently using this Parameter.xml I need to create setParameters_...xml file.

My question are:

1) It seems I have to manually create the Parameter.xml file. Is my assumption correct?

2) How do I create the setParameter...xml file?

Please guide me through this process or good resource which I can use as reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the description of `Parameter.xml` and `setParameters.xml`. It seems you want to create **web deploy package** in TFS2015 vNext Build.

You can directly use below MSBuild Arguments:

```
/p:OutDir=$(build.stagingDirectory) /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
```

For the sample you can take a look at below blogs:

- [Building Websites in Team Foundation Build 2015](http://www.deliveron.com/blog/building-websites-team-foundation-build-2015/)
- [Build and Deploy Azure Web Apps using Team Foundation Server/Services vNext Builds](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/04/01/build-and-deploy-azure-web-apps-using-team-foundation-serverservices-vnext-builds/)

---

You can also enable web deploy package creation within the [Visual Studio Build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/build/visual-studio-build) task. Simply pass the following MS Build arguments:

MSBuild Arguments: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=<name of your profile>`

On Variables tab page DeploymentConfiguration has to be configured. It must be the Name of the publish Profile (filename of the pubxml file). If the file Name is Build.pubxml the publish profile is Build.

for example:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=Build
```

For the sample you can take a look at this blog:

- [An ASP.NET MVC Site That’s Easy to Deploy from a TFS Build](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/08/an-asp-net-mvc-site-thats-easy-to-deploy-from-a-tfs-build/)